# Supplying Kendo Autocomplete Data based on Kendo DropDownList Selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Autocomplete control, which should populate its data based on a selected value of a parent Kendo-dropdownlist.

I wonder how to go about doing this. I am using MVC 4 and a Razor view.

I have tried to do it like this but this didn't work:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.CustomerId).Name("customerDropDownList").Events(e=>e.Close("selectedItem")).Text(ViewBag.Customers[Model.CustomerId].TextValue).AutoBind(false).DataTextField("TextValue").DataValueField("Id").BindTo(ViewBag.Customers).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 215px" })
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().Name("customerOrders").Filter("startsWith").Placeholder("Customer Order Number.")
</div>


<script>
    $('#customersDropDownList').kendoDropDownList({
       close : function selectItem (e) {
            var item = e.item;
            var text = item.text();
            // Use the selected item or its text
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Change (or onClose or OnSelect) event of dropdownlist, you can simply set the datasource of autocomplete  using local or remote data something like:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.CustomerId).Name("customerDropDownList").Events(e=>e.Change("onDropdownChange")).Text(ViewBag.Customers[Model.CustomerId].TextValue).AutoBind(false).DataTextField("TextValue").DataValueField("Id").BindTo(ViewBag.Customers).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 215px" })
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().Name("customerOrders").Filter("startsWith").Placeholder("Customer Order Number.")
</div>    

<script>
    function onDropdownChange(e) {

        var selectedValue = this.value();    
        // If you have local data for every dropdown option, wrap them in individual datasource and switch accordingly.
        var dataSourceForoption1 = kendo.data.DataSource({ data: ["John", "Adam", "binbsr:)", "ginni"] });                        
        var autocomplete = $("#customerOrders").data("kendoAutoComplete");
        autocomplete.setDataSource(dataSourceForoption1); // For now, same dataSource for every option

    }    

</script>
```

Hope it helps.